# asp.net core kendo ui grid custom command template not work

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

here is my Kendo ui grid command:

```
                columns.Command(cmd =>
                {
                    cmd.Custom("CustomButton").TemplateId("commandsTemplate");

                }).Title("Commands").Width(250);
```

and this is template:

```
<script id="commandsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class='dropdown dropdown-inline'>
         <button type='button' class='btn btn-hover-brand btn-elevate-hover btn-icon btn-sm btn-icon-md' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'> <i class='flaticon-more-1'></i> </button>
         <div class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
            @(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Details", "Blabla", new { id = "#: NameEn#" }, new { @class = "dropdown-item" }))
         </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

but generated url is exactly:

```
http://localhost:56516/Blabla/Details/%23%3A%20NameEn%23
```

Answer (score 0):

The link in the template is created using razor syntax, which runs on the server before being sent to the browser. The server has no idea what #:NameEn# means and so uses it literally in the generated url.

You cannot use kendo templating syntax within razor syntax. One is evaluated client side and the other server side so they do not mix. In this case, simply replace the Html.ActionLink line with actual html within which you can use #:NameEn#

So something like:

```
<a href="/Blabla/Details/#:NameEn#"></a>
```